# AWS DynamoDB trigger invocation speed and synchronization

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Do triggers on DynamoDB tables have some sort of internal synchronization to keep everything in the order it is supposed to be? 
Example: my trigger batch size is 1 and it's configured to always start reading from the latest entry. Two entries are made to the DB at one millisecond apart (or at the same time). I don't know the time it takes for the trigger and lambda function to be invoked but let's say for argument's sake it's longer than the time between DB entries (>1ms). Can I be sure that both lambda invocations don't receive the data from the second DB entry?

Comment: Do you mean Dynamodb streams triggering the lambda function?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  I should've been more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynamoDB Streams doesn't send duplicates.

> No, DynamoDB Streams is designed so that every update made to your
>   table will be represented exactly once in the stream.

**DynamoDB Streams guarantees the following:**

> Each stream record appears exactly once in the stream. For each item
>   that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear in the
>   same sequence as the actual modifications to the item.

DynamoDB Streams provides a **time-ordered sequence** of item-level changes made to data in a table.

As there is few milli-seconds difference between the update 1 and 2, Lambda should get two streams in the time ordered sequence (i.e. update 1 and then update 2).

**Processing Streams Records on Lamdba:-**

> The Amazon Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams records sent to your AWS
>   Lambda function are strictly serialized, **per shard**. This means that if
>   you put two records in the same shard, Lambda guarantees that your
>   Lambda function will be successfully invoked with the first record
>   before it is invoked with the second record. If the invocation for one
>   record times out, is throttled, or encounters any other error, Lambda
>   will retry until it succeeds (or the record reaches its 24-hour
>   expiration) before moving on to the next record. The ordering of
>   records across different shards is not guaranteed, and processing of
>   each shard happens in parallel.

**Stream-based event sources** –

> If you create a Lambda function that processes events from
>   stream-based services (Amazon Kinesis Streams or DynamoDB streams),
>   the number of shards per stream is the unit of concurrency. If your
>   stream has 100 active shards, there will be 100 Lambda functions
>   running concurrently. Then, each Lambda function processes events on a
>   shard in the order that they arrive.

**Short Answer:-**

- Stream ensure that there is no duplicates. So there is no way that 2
  Lambda invocations receive same data
- Reg the processing of stream records i.e. whether the second update
  processing starts after the first update processing depends on shard 
  per stream (unit of concurrency)

Because shards have a lineage (parent and children), applications must always process a parent shard before it processes a child shard. This will ensure that the stream records are also processed in the correct order. Use **[DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html)** if you wanted to preserve the correct processing order.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!